# How to add custom error message for model property from Json file?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, localization

I stored all Strings for localization in Json file. like below.

```
[
  {
    "Key": "screen",
    "Value": "Screen No"
  },
  {
    "Key": "go",
    "Value": "Go!"
  },
  {
    "Key": "titlehome",
    "Value": "Search Particular Screan"
  },
  {
    "Key": "home",
    "Value": "Home"
  }]
```

So How can I access these string in Model for data Notation.
I create a static function  `Utils.value("screen")` and return the value of that key.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Nasimbahar,

```
    public class josnResult
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    var _listResult= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<josnResult>>(jsonValue);

    josnResult _josnResult = _listResult.Where(t => t.Key == "screen").FirstOrDefault();

    if (_josnResult != null)
    {
        var _val = _josnResult.Value;
    }
```

Comment: i did this part. I want to show model error message from these json strings . I did this like below `[Required(ErrorMessage =Utils.Value("requeredmessage")]` but it give the error that an attribute argument must be a constant expression.

Comment: please add some description about your solution

Comment: Hi, 
Create model(josnResult)
and then deserialize your string
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<josnResult>>(YOURJSONVALUE); in list then you can get easily your value